# mobile asp.net techniques

Tags: asp.net, mobile

What are your techniques to using mobile with asp.net, I know how to detect mobile but I'm stumped trying to find a good way to show my pages on a mobile device.

I'm thinking of just doing a Multi-View and showing the mobile view when they are mobile, however that would not work with our masterpage unless I do same, I'd rather just have the page redirect to a mobile version.

But I'd like this to happen automatically, don't want to add the code to every page, I've used an HttpModule but it causes every object in the website to use it, only want this on aspx pages so I just used a user control that it put on the top of the master page.

I also added a folder called mobile in the tree that contains folders for each mobile device, so if they go to ~/Account/Login.aspx it redirects to ~/Account/Mobile/IPhone/Login.aspx but i had to exclude the masterpage in the mobile device or it'll be in an endless loop :)

I like the way MVC does it where they have a custom ViewEngine that just redirects, but I can't go MVC due to some ASP.NET controls that my company requires.

Ideas?

Comment: What kind of phones are you planning on supporting? For instance, a page that works on an iPhone is not necessarily going to work on a Sony Ericsson K700.

Also be aware that people may be using browsers like Opera Mini. Opera works even on really basic mobiles and uses a proxy server so that it can often reformat pages in a way that works well.

Comment: Planning on making it for both, idea I used will work with multiple phones since I can use a folder for each type of phone.. "~/Account/Mobile/BlackBerry/Login.aspx" .. another technique I'm working with, is using a custom file extension and HttpModule, and instead of using directories and if i go to Login.aspx and im mobile, it'll go to Login.mobile, but render the page as an aspx page. Unfortunately, this won't make it support multiple phones..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on the particular site and what has prompted you to consider having a mobile version of the site. How much content do you have that is unsuitable for mobile browsers (e.g. Flash, AJAX) ? How complex are these custom controls that you mentioned?

Personally I think it is best to try to design your main site to be compatible for people browsing on more recent smartphones (e.g. iphone, Android) since they are becoming very popular and increasingly capable. These phones have browsers that are normally based on WebKit so testing in Chrome or Safari would give at least some idea of how well your page would work.

If necessary then you could use slightly different stylesheets for desktop and mobile. You make the page more accessible by hiding unimportant content and simplifying navigation.

ASP .NET actually has a complex device filtering system built in, so you can change parts of the page, even the master page to use, depending on the current browser. See here: http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2008/08/14/more-on-device-filtering-with-asp.net-server-control-properties.aspx. You just need to make sure that your browser definitions are up to date.

Avoid complex ASP .NET controls like GridViews since you have less control over the HTML and CSS. Controls like the ListView are much more flexible.

Some functionality like AJAX might be a bit buggy on certain devices, especially if you are using AJAX UpdatePanels. You could use an emulator to test these scenarios. Alternatively you could disable these features on mobile devices. That's assuming your even using them.

To accommodate low end devices you could have a separate mobile site that runs in parallel. To create mobile pages, you inherit from **System.Web.UI.MobileControls.MobilePage** instead of the normal Page class. W3Schools has some useful information: http://www.w3schools.com/dotnetmobile/control_mobilepage.asp. Note that mobile web forms is now deprecated though so it is not considered the way forward.

If you are going to run two or more sites in parallel and you have complex logic needed by both then you could create a class library to hold the shared functionality. It would cut out some code duplication.

To avoid an infinite loop when redirecting to the mobile version, just check the current URL to see if it contains the base URL for the mobile site. It might be easiest just to do the redirect on the main page but have a link somewhere on every page that goes to the mobile version when clicked.

Overall it is a very complex subject so perhaps consider getting a suitable book.